# If statement on xamarin forms

Tags: if-statement, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently on my application when i run it the code is working correctly, except when i add a 'symptom' that already belongs in the 'symptom history' , currently when i add a symptom which is already added in the symptom history the app gives out the message "Duplicate Symptom", "You already have recorded this symptom" and "Historical Symptom", "This symptom is in your history - Please restore from here". How can i get to it to only display "Historical Symptom", "This symptom is in your history - Please restore from here" message.

Currently if the symptom isnt deleted and moved to the symptom history the app will only output the "Duplicate Symptom", "You already have recorded this symptom" message corrrectly.

The functionality is working correctly just need to only display that one message on the function instead of both of them.

This is the current code on my button:

```
 async void btnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);

        //If the autocomplete is not empty - add that symptom to the user symptom table

        if (AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd != null)
        {

            //If the user already has symptoms, loop through them to make sure that they are not adding a duplicate

            if (UserSymptoms.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (usersymptom item in UserSymptoms)
                {
                    if (item.Symptomid == AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Duplicate Symptom", "You already have recorded this symptom", "OK");


                        return;
                    }

                    //Check if it is not active (i.e in SYmptom History)

                    else

                    {

                        UserSymptomToAdd.Symptomid = AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id;
                        UserSymptomToAdd.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
                        UserSymptomToAdd.Datetimeadded = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        UserSymptomToAdd.IsActive = true;




                        try
                        {
                            await usersymptommanager.AddUserSymptom(UserSymptomToAdd);
                            await AddInitialFeedback(UserSymptomToAdd.Id);
                            //await DisplayAlert("Symptom Added", "Your Symptom has been added", "OK");

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Analytics.TrackEvent("App Screen: " + Title + ": " + ex);
                            //await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
```

The code for my history message:

```
  async void CheckSymptomInHistory(string id)
    {
        foreach (string item in SymptomHistoryIDs)
        {
            if (id == item)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Historical Symptom", "This symptom is in your history - Please restore from here", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try commenting this line of code `CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);`

Comment: @G.hakim When i comment that out i only get the "Duplication Symptom" message now and no longer get the "Historical Symptom" message.

Comment: is it not what you wanted here?

Comment: @G.hakim No i need it to only show the "Historical Symptom" message when the symptom is currently in the symptom history. At the minute when the symptom is in the symptom history its shows up both theses messages.

Comment: Okay check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing I see is that you're doing a null-check on `AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd` after you used it for `CheckSymptomInHistory`. I would put the null-check before `CheckSymptomInHistory`, otherwise you may be subjected to a `NullReferenceException`:

```cs
if (AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd == null)
{
    // Display an error message?
    return;
}

// AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd is not null, proceed to use it
CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);
```

I would then change the return type of `CheckSymptomInHistory` to return `bool` like so:

```cs
bool CheckSymptomInHistory(string id)
{
    foreach (string item in SymptomHistoryIDs)
    {
        if (id == item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in your handler, check the return type of the `CheckSymptomInHistory` method like so:

```cs
bool isSymptomInHistory = CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);
if (isSymptomInHistory)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Historical Symptom", "This symptom is in your history - Please restore from here", "OK");
    return;
}

// Symptom is not in history, carry on as normal
```

Comment: Thanks mates, that did it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to achieve what you are trying;

Comment the First line of code in your method i.e.  `CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);`

In the ForEach Loop:

```
foreach (usersymptom item in UserSymptoms)
            {
                if (item.Symptomid == AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Duplicate Symptom", "You already have recorded this symptom", "OK");


                    return;
                }

                else if(CheckSymptomInHistory(AutoCompleteSymptomToAdd.Id);)
                 {

                   await DisplayAlert("Historical Symptom", "This symptom is in your history - Please restore from here", "OK");
                 }
```

Where CheckSystemInHistory is as below:

```
 private bool CheckSymptomInHistory(string id)
{
  foreach (string item in SymptomHistoryIDs)
  {
      if (id == item)
      {
         return true;
      }
  }

  return false;
 }
```

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I cant upvote yet until i reach 15 reputation, only at 12, otherwise i would :(

Comment: @G.hakim Thanks